# How to sync data insert-update-delete between source/destination in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm a beginner in SSIS and i want to know a simple way to sync data between source/destination like:
Insert - Update - Delete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the Insert-Updet-Delete with the `Merge Join` and `Conditional Split components`.
Let's consider you have a table `Employees` in SQL Server as your data source component and a table EmployeesSTG as your source data component for data existing in your staging database :

Your data in the DB Application Source :

[image]

You need to sort both dataset why because merge join component needs data to be sorted either in an ascending order or descending order so here we will sort the data in an ascending order with sort component available in SSIS :

[image]

This is how the `Sort component` is configured :

[image]

This is how the `Merge Join` is configured :

[image]

After merging data, you need to split data since you did `left outer join` if data matches then only both sides data will be there otherwise right side will be replaced with a null so unmatched data which has null value on right side you will considered as NEW data so you will insert that and rest you will match data column wise like if Position for example  does not match with left side then you will update it.

[image]

Since you have split data into 3 parts so we need 3 destinations.

1- As per first condition data will be inserted so for this we will use `OLEDB Destination component`.

[image]

2- As per second condition data will be updated so for this we will use `OLEDB Command component` to write update command :

```
UPDATE Employees
SET FullName=?,
Position=?
WHERE EmployeeID=?
```

And this is the mapping overview :

[image]

3- As per the 3rd condition, you will delete the records in the staging table using an `OLEDB Command component` to write update command :

```
DELETE FROM Employees
WHERE EmployeeID=?
```

And this is the mapping overview :

[image]